# ES6 Arrow Function this

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why arrow function this return window object and how I return obj ?

```
let obj = {
  name:"Maxi",
  fn  :()=>this,
}

console.log(obj.fn())
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why arrow function this return window object

Because arrow functions capture the current value of `this` at the time they are created.

> how I return obj

Don't use an arrow function if you don't want to capture the current value of `this`.

Comment: why  this return obj ?
let obj = {
  members:["Murad","Maxi"],
  team:"Fuckers",
  fn  : function()
  {
     return this.members.map(name=>this)
  }   
}

console.log(obj.fn())

Comment: Because the current value of `this` when `obj.fn()` is called is the same as the value of `obj`.

Comment: not making much sense. please give more examples

Answer (score 1):

With arrow functions, `this` is not bound to its own context.

Arrow functions do not create their own `this` context, so `this` has its original meaning from the enclosing context which is `window` in your case.